# Show that two direct limits (infinitely generated Abelian groups) are not isomorphic

Tags: category-theory, abelian-groups, limits-colimits, monomorphisms

I have a process which generates infinite sequences $S=S_0\rightarrowtail S_1 \rightarrowtail S_2\ldots$ of finite Abelian groups $S_i$ connected by monomorphisms $S_i\rightarrowtail S_{i+1}$ (injective group homomorphisms). Each sequence thus corresponds to a functor $S:\omega\rightarrow Ab$ from the usual linear order on the counting numbers $\omega=\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$ to the category of Abelian groups. Since it is guaranteed that the minimal number of generators of $S_i$ is strictly smaller than of $S_{i+1}$, the direct limit $\varinjlim S$ is not finitely generated.

I am interested in sufficient conditions for the elements $S_i^A$ and $S_i^B$ of two such sequences $S^A$ and $S^B$ such that the existence of an isomorphism between the direct limits can be excluded. I am rather new to infinitely generated Abelian groups, thus, any reference to standard approaches/sufficient theorems I could try out would be helpful.

## Additional information

- Every sequence $S^A:\omega\rightarrow Ab$ factors as $S^A=G F^A$, $F^A:\omega\rightarrow P$ and $G:P\rightarrow Ab$, where $P$ is a poset. The functor G is thereby the same for every sequence.
- There is a forgetful functor $U:P\rightarrow Set$ from $P$ to convex bounded subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ which maps morphisms to standard set inclusions, i.e. $U(P_1\subseteq P_2)=U(P_1)\subseteq U(P_2)$.
- The sequences $S^A=G F^A$ are constructed such that $\varinjlim U F^A=\mathbb{R}^2$.
- I don't have a closed formula for the structure of the finite Abelian groups $S^A_i$. However, for small enough $U F_i^A$, I am able to computationally decompose $S^A_i$ into the direct product of cyclic groups of prime power order.
- I have some limited control over the construction of the sequences $S$. Specifically, I can construct $S$ such that $S_i$ and $S_{i+1}$ contain cyclic subgroups $C_i\subseteq S_i$ and $C_{i+1}\subseteq S_{i+1}$, where $|C_i|$ divides $|C_{i+1}|$, such that the monomorphism $S_i\rightarrowtail S_{i+1}$ maps $C_i$ into $C_{i+1}$.
- When only concentrating on these subgroups, and by setting $s_0=1$, $s_{i+1}=\frac{|C_{i+1}|}{|C_{i}|}$ , I get the direct system $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z} \rightarrowtail \mathbb{Z}/(s_1\mathbb{Z}) \rightarrowtail \mathbb{Z}/(s_1s_2\mathbb{Z}) \rightarrowtail\ldots$ equivalent to
  $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z} \rightarrowtail \frac{1}{s_1}\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z} \rightarrowtail \frac{1}{s_1s_2}\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z} \rightarrowtail\ldots$.
- I can now define two sequences $S^A$ and $S^B$ such $S^A_0=S^B_0$, and such that $s^A_i = i$ and $s^B_i=p=const$. Then, the direct limits of these subgroups are given by $\bigcup\left(\frac{1}{s_i!}\mathbb{Z}\right)/\mathbb{Z} = \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$, respectively by $\bigcup\left(\frac{1}{p^i}\mathbb{Z}\right)/ \mathbb{Z} = \mathbb{Z}[1/p] / \mathbb{Z} = \mathbb{Z}(p^\infty)$, with $\mathbb{Z}(p^\infty)$ the Prüfer p-group.
- This makes me believe that the direct limits of $S^A$ and $S^B$ should be *not* isomorphic, too. However, currently I lack understanding of what would be sufficient to show additionally to be able to prove this.

Comment: Surely without further control of the rest of the groups the direct limits could still be abstractly isomorphic. You've phrased all of this in categorical language using functors. Why do so if you aren't ultimately interested in isomorphisms which are "natural" in some sense? Clearly you're wanting the cyclic bits to match up and you want to say that since they don't in your example, the direct limits aren't isomorphic.

Comment: @Joshua : I agree that, what I currently showed,  is not sufficient. The question is "are there clever ways to conclude that the cyclic bits don't match up without explicitly listing them and then comparing the lists?" Maybe something in the direction of what I already showed? I mainly used categorical language for the "additional information" section, which might or might not provide useful information. I also tend to think in this language...

Comment: It sounds to me like you should compute some explicit examples of the direct limit from your construction. For instance, if you can force the groups to be p-groups for differing p's, the limits will obviously not be isomorphic. At the level of abstraction you've presented, I doubt much more can be said.